# Regarding Publishing Kinect Depth Image

Tags: ros, kinect, libopencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I have  kinect Depth image as mentioned below. I am trying to publish this from my node. I am having problem in converting my image to buffer  which is needed to send it as a message. Please find below my code. I would be glad if somecan guide where I am doing a mistake.

///////////////////////////---code--////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
image_transport::Publisher publisher_depth = it.advertise("kinectcamera/depth", 1);

kinectDepthImage = cvCreateImage( cvSize(640,480),IPL_DEPTH_16U,1);
/*
here I store the image from Kinect
*/
cvShowImage("Depth", kinectDepthImage); // This shows me fine the image. I have no issue.

//Now I try to publish it i any of the two ways And this is where It fails.

 cv::WImageBuffer_16u depthBufer(kinectDepthImage); 
or 
 cv::WImageBuffer1_16u depthBufer(kinectDepthImage);


sensor_msgs::ImagePtr depth_msg = sensor_msgs::CvBridge::cvToImgMsg(depthBufer.Ipl(), "mono16");

publisher_depth.publish(depth_msg);


my error is " /opt/ros/fuerte/include/opencv2/core/wimage.hpp:243: cv::WImage<T>::WImage(IplImage*) [with T = short unsigned int, IplImage = _IplImage]: Assertion `!img || img->depth == Depth()' failed.
pass1Aborted (core dumped) "
```

Please help me with this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49918/regarding-publishing-kinect-depth-image/) by [Subhasis](https://answers.ros.org/users/3414/subhasis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2012-12-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure why it's failing and whether this would make a difference, but have you tried using the C++ API for OpenCV?

```
image_transport::Publisher publisher_depth = it.advertise("kinectcamera/depth", 1);

// create image
cv::Mat kinectDepthImage = cv::Mat(480, 640, CV_16UC1);

// fill out image - for example
for (int u = 0; u < 640; ++u)
for (int v = 0; v < 480; ++v)
  kinectDepthImage.at<uint16_t>(v,u) = some value here;

sensor_msgs::ImagePtr depth_msg = sensor_msgs::CvBridge::cvToImgMsg(kinectDepthImage);
```

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2012-12-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0